# What is f-ing my data?

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting a `NSData *` and trying to get it byte by byte but the data is filled with `f`.

```
NSData *Data = getData();
cout << "The log way:" << endl;
NSLog(@"%@", Data);
cout << "The data way:" << endl;
char *data = (char *)[Data bytes];
for(int i = 0; i < [Data length]; i++)
{
    cout.width(2);
    cout.fill(0);
    cout << hex << (int)(data[i]) << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

What I'm getting as output:

```
The log way:
/* something long about time and file */<1f9cb0f8>
The data way:
1f ffffff9c ffffffb0 fffffff8
```

How can I get this data as `int`s without all those `f`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `char` data type is of undefined signedness, and it seems your compiler (gcc or clang?) decided it should be signed. Therefore, when you cast a `char` to a larger type, sign extension is used, which fills the extra bits with the same value the most significant bit has. For bytes with a value larger than `0x7F`, the most significant bit is set, so it breaks the enlargement.

What you want is zero extension, which zeroes the extra bits. You can get it by using the `unsigned char` type.

This should do it:

```
unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *)[Data bytes];
```

By the way, `-[NSData bytes]` return a `const` pointer. You should honor this and mark your pointer as `const` too:

```
const unsigned char *data = (const unsigned char *)[Data bytes];
```

Comment: I think llvm is the compiler here. I remember char was unsigned... well, guess apple lives in their own world.

Comment: I'm fairly sure gcc behaves like this too. I do recall however that there's a compiler option for the signedness of `char`. Otherwise, you may also use `uint8_t`, which leaves out any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

That is data as ints, sort of. The data is split into bytes and sign-extended to ints. As bytes, your data is `1f 9c b0 f8`. `9c`, `b0`, and `f8` are all negative, so they are sign extended by making the extra bits all 1, which is why you are getting a bunch of `f`s.

Comment: You can change `char *data` to `unsigned char *data` to force zero-extension, since all numbers will be treated as positive.